# Customize a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview which shows data. But i want to customize the cells and i need a little help. So i have a nib for the tableview (HistoryViewController.xib). I just added the class and nib to customize the tableview cells (HistoryViewTableCell).
What are the steps i have to do next? I have this code already:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"PickupAddress"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Be clear, what r u trying to ask? . please edit ur question

Comment: This shows animations, but the way to change the look of the cells is good. http://www.raywenderlich.com/49311/advanced-table-view-animations-tutorial-drop-in-cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link ..

[Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/)

good demo with project try this

[Customize Table View Cells for UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code -

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
        HistoryViewTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewTableCell"];
            if (cell == nil) {
                // Create a temporary UIViewController to instantiate the custom cell.
                UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryViewTableCell" bundle:nil];
                // Grab a pointer to the custom cell.
                cell = (HistoryViewTableCell *)temporaryController.view;

            }

        return cell;
        }
```

**OR**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HistoryViewTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return cell;
}
```